# How do multiuser group/directory permissions work?

Tags: permissions

I have 2 users, lets say `agus` and `jenkins`

user jenkins belongs to `agus` group

```
$ grep 'agus' /etc/group
agus:x:1011:nexus,jenkins
```

I have a folder `/home/agus/temp`, and I want both users to be able to `rwx` in that folder, I executed

```
$ sudo chmod -R 775 /home/agus/temp/
```

But when I do that `jenkins` user has no permissions to write in the folder, and if I execute this

```
$ sudo chmod --recursive a+rwx /home/agus/temp/
```

`jenkins` has permissions but `agus` does not

Comment: I'm proposing an edit to the title, to avoid confusion with the Jenkins software package.

Comment: Some vital information is missing: who is the owner and who is the group owner of the temp directory?

Comment: Thank you @JohanMyréen the owner of that folder is `agus` and the group is `agus`, `jenkins` only belongs to the group

Comment: Something looks off here. Could you include the commands that are failing for you?